# Convert Cortona VRML to X3D

Tags: vrml, x3d

I want to convert a VRML file exported from RapidAuthor to X3D, so that X3DOM can read it.

Problem : Cortona VRML is extended ; I tried many software (aopt, X3D-Edit and Meshlab for ex.) but none could convert it (it crashes or just cannot perform).

Did anyone already succeed it ?

Comment: Do you have an example file exported by RapidAuthor, so we could try to see which types of non-standard nodes might be the issue ?

Comment: An example of Cortona VRML can be downloaded on : http://download.cortona3d.com/public/C3DDemoPack-12Q1/C3DDemoPack-12Q1/General%20-%20Pump/Published%20Examples/portal/content/IPC/Pump%20IPC%20-%20Complete.wrl . The global Cortona export (VRML + JS + HTML) can also be seen on http://download.cortona3d.com/public/C3DDemoPack-12Q1/C3DDemoPack-12Q1/General%20-%20Pump/Published%20Examples/portal/content/IPC/Pump%20IPC%20-%20Complete.htm

Comment: Thanks for the example files

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you're not going to find an existing tool that handle this type of file out of the box (I even tried it in the not-yet-publicly-available BS Content Studio and it just crashed).

You'd need to manually (or if you have many models, write a program or VrmlPad macro to automate it) get rid of the PROTOs, the 4 Cortona-only nodes (IntegerSequencer, TransformSensor, HTMLText, Panel) and remove the vrmlscript Script nodes before converter tools could handle it.

Only then you will be able to convert to X3D (or other formats), then you'd still need to write javascript for reproducing the type of interactions you had in the Cortona version.

---

**Basically, your only choices are**:

- write your own converter
- get someone to write it for you
- wait until Cortona adds a X3DOM export option
- (or use another tool than RapidAuthor)

You mentioned that you cleaned up the file enough that it works in Contact so you could try opening it in [BS Studio](http://www.bitmanagement.com/download/BS_Content_Studio/BS_Content_Studio_Installer_x86.exe), but you'd still end up having to redo the animations because its X3DOM support is very minimal.

Comment: I finally succeeded converting it... As BitManagement could open the original file, I had to delete extension line by line always checking if it still can be open as there are inner dependencies (for example TransformSensor is used as variable and in Javascript code). But I could convert the cleaned VRML file to X3D with AOPT. Problem is that now only BitManagement can open the VRML file ; with X3DOM the debug mode says that many nodes are not supported ! For example ProtoBody and Protodeclare, where these are used many times... Isn't AOPT supposed to be fully compatible with X3DOM ?

Comment: I seem to recall AOPT was created with InstantReality in mind, while X3DOM that came later only supports a smaller set a nodes, so you might have an easier time converting the original static 3D model (before it was imported in RapidAuthor to add interactions, as I assume it was created in a CAD application ?) and then recreate the interactions in javascript, rather than trying to convert the VRML file. Although to be honest I don't really follow X3DOM's latest developments that much anymore, the API of [three.js](http://threejs.org) feels easier to work with and has more contributors.

Comment: The problem is that Cortona is really useful for authoring. Importing a CATIA CAD file, I can easily create different views and define parts of the assembly to be interactive or create animations, I don't think so other software can do it. Anyway thanks.